# how to use multiple .tflite models in android studio flutter

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

please anyone explain me how to use multiple .Tflite models in android studio with flutter
needs to create an app that detects both flower and leaves of different plants so it needs to implement multiple machine learning models which uses same camera frame and displays the result

Comment: Technically possible. It needs to create two interpreter instances after attaching two tflite models to the application and then run inferences towards them based on your needs.

Comment: To my knowlage tf.lite.interpreter is a functionality only available in tensorflow core library, but I don't think it is possible to use tensorflow features inside flutter. @JaesungChung do you have a workaround for this?